# sybase drop index error "Cannot drop the index,because it doesn't exist in the system catalogs"

Tags: sybase

[image: ERROR during dropping the index]

I got this error while dropping the index ZQT64_CUA_LOGSYS for the table name ZQT64.

"Cannot drop the index 'ZQT64.ZQT64_CUA_LOGSYS', because it doesn't exist in the
system catalogs."

Seeing this i tried creating the index again, Where it showed "There is already an index on table 'ZQT64' named 'ZQT64_CUA_LOGSYS'"

[image: ERROR during re-creating the index]

Could someone suggest me what is the issue and how can I Drop the index?

Answer (score 0):

Your `create index` command shows a user of `SAPSR3`.

I'm going to guess that you're not logged in as the user `SAPSR3` (eg, perhaps you're logged in as `sapsa`).  If this is the case try changing to user `SAPSR3` to drop the index, eg:

```
use TST
go
-- switch to user SAPSR3
setuser 'SAPSR3'
go
drop index ZQT64.ZQT64_CUA_LOGSYS
go
-- switch back to your original user
setuser
go
```

ASE is a bit flaky in this area:

- while you can provide database and user names for the `create index`
  command, these identifiers are not supported by the `drop index`
  command
- error 3701 (`cannot drop the index ... doesn't exist in the system
  catalog`) is a bit misleading; it should probably say something like
  `you don't own an object named ZQT64` (or something similar)